# Intercept and handle missing translations in helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I have a helper function that generates useful HTML markup. My functions are usually called with some parameters, including some text translated with I18n `my_helper( t(:translation_symbol) )`.

I use I18n `t` translation helper for that, which (if left untouched) outputs some `<span class="translation missing">...</span>` for texts without translation

I was wondering how to best "intercept" this translation missing so

- I can render them appropriately in my helpers
- Normal behavior outside my helpers

In my views I should be able to call both

```
<%= my_helper(t(:my_text)) %> # My helper needs to handle missing translations
<%= t(:my_text) %> # I want default I18n markup (or a custom one) '<span class="translation missing">fr.my_text</span>
```

My helper

```
def my_helper(text=nil)
  # Suppose my_text doesn't have a translation, text will have value 
  # => '<span class="translation-missing">fr.my_text</span>'
  if translation_missing?(text)
    # Code to handle missing translation
    doSomething(remove_translation_missing_markup(text))
    notify_translation_missing
  else
    doSomething(text)
  end
end

def translation_missing?(text)
  # Uses some regex pattern to detect '<span class="translation-missing">'
end
def remove_translation_missing_markup(text)
  # Uses some regex pattern to extract my_text from '<span class="translation-missing">fr.my_text</span>'
end
```

Is there a better way around this ? I feel bad about using a dirty regex solution.

EDIT : extra requirements

- No additional markup on views : I don't want to look at my files individually to add `raise: true` or `default: xxx` for every translation. If there is a need to change the behavior everywhere I can override the `t` method.
- In my helpers, I need a convenient way to manipulate, just the translated text if the translation was found, but for missing translations, I need to easily be able to extract the full path of the translation (`fr.namespace.translation_symbol`), and the original translation symbol (`translation_symbol`), so I can add myself `translation_missing` in my custom markup.

EDIT2 : I am thinking of something like that

- Override `t` helper to `rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData => e`
- If the exception is raised, create and return a custom object that

  - If rendered in a html.erb, will output the usual `<span class="translation..."`
  - Has useful fields (translation path, translation_string) that I can reuse in my helpers

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution that got you what you wanted?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti Actually I was on to something I believe would be quite cool, but I couldn't get the final text to render as HTML in my views. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072697/custom-object-that-converts-to-html-in-view)

Comment: Okay, cool.  Hope you eventually get what you want working.  I don't think I'm sold on the idea of handling missing translations at runtime, though: I think if they're a big enough problem for your app, then you'd want to make sure there are no missing translations before you make an app deployment, which is what [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) can assist with.

Comment: I work in a very agile development context and my client often doesn't know yet what kind of text he'd want there (and, if he knows in English, he doesn't know yet in French maybe). Having the title popup really helps me find the translation very fast if I want to do a live change (I am not using the default lazy lookup which is 0% reusable, I translate by concept instead, the drawback being that it can be hard to find my translation).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can leverage the fact that I18n can be configured to **raise an exception when translation missing**. You can either set `ActionView::Base.raise_on_missing_translations = true` to globally raise the exception upon missing translations or you can pass `:raise => true` option to the `t` translation helper.

Update: since you are already using `t` helpers in your views and you don't want to change them, I think the only option for you is overriding the `t` helper in your `ApplicationHelper`:

```
# ApplicationHelper

def t(key, options = {})
  # try to translate as usual
  I18n.t(key, options.merge(raise: true)
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData => e
  # do whatever you want on translation missing, e.g. send notification to someone
  # ...
  "Oh-oh!"
end
```

This helper either returns the translated text or "oh-oh" if translation missing. And it should work as-is in your current views.

Comment: This is going to generate exceptions outside my helpers. But outside my helpers, I don't want the exception or it means my website is going to crash. And if possible I'd like to avoid using extra markup in my views (I'm sorry but I cannot afford to go through all my views to add `raise: true` case by case).

Comment: I see. But basically I still need to add some markup that I can detect later... I was thinking that maybe when calling `my_helper(t(:my_text))`, `t(:my_text)` could output some sort of intermediate object that can be interpreted by my helpers easily, but if called outside (like in a capture block), the `to_s` (or whatever method is called) would generate the default `<span class="missing..."` markup

Answer (score 2):

Since missing translations seems to be a pain point in your app, rather than have your app code be constantly on the lookout for whether a translation exists or not, if possible I would advocate ensuring that you *always* have translations for *every* potential call to `t`, regardless of locale (this is all on the assumption that the `:translation_symbol` keys in your calls to `my_helper(t(:translation_symbol))` are all static, kept in your `config/locales` directory, and aren't generated dynamically).

You can do this using the [I18n-tasks gem](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) to:

- Ensure your app does not have missing *or* unused keys, so you should be able to delete the missing translation handling parts of your helper methods
- Make your test suite/build process *fail* if there are any missing or unused translations, so no one else that touches the codebase accidentally sneaks any through.  See [instructions on copying over their RSpec test](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks#installation).

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the default option to the translate method as follows:

```
<%= t(:my_text, default: "not here") %>
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#defaults for details about setting defaults for the `I18n.translate` method.

Comment: Writing `default` values is like writing the translations already. I don't want that. That default feels pretty useless for me. And how do I detect the translation was actually missing inside my helper ?